# How can I get response from UIWebView page to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm using `UIWebView` as a subview in a `UIViewController`. What this `WebView` does is it allows user to submit a form and that form responses as `JSON` object. How can I get this response to an app? I'm not able to find what response comes. All I know is that response is `JSON`. I even tried using `shouldStartLoadWithRequest()`. But it only shows URL. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: UIWebView has navigationDelegate methods which may help you.

Comment: Can you elaborate this please?

Comment: try with NSCachedURLResponse *jsonResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:webView.request];
    NSLog(@"%@",[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)jsonResponse.response allHeaderFields]);  also in webViewDidFinishLoad method.

Comment: i hope that worked.

Comment: I have used these couple of lines in webViewDidLoad() and shouldStartLoadWithRequest(). Both results jsonResponse getting NULL value. If I'm doing it correctly, maybe I should confirm with client if they are really giving JSON response on form submission.

Comment: - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation  . you can try this method of navigationDelegate if your webview is getting any redirection after post.

Comment: Having hard time dealing with this. It gives response as null in both cases.

Comment: I wish you could tell me what exactly to write in didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation(). Maybe I'm doing all wrong

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'window.location'. A little uncomfortable but fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing this method may be it helps you

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

and check for the navigation types out of these
`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIWebViewNavigationType) {
    UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked,
    UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted,
    UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward,
    UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload,
    UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted,
    UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther
}`

Comment: I tried to implement this method but how can I find response returned by form? This method only give two parameters request and navigationType

Comment: @HirenPrajapati Is the form is at ur site or any site?